# Access Terminal and Run Shell Script in Ionic

Tags: android, shell, ionic-framework, terminal

I'm currently developing an app using Ionic framework and at some point, I need to access terminal to run a command. In my case, suppose I have an executable file which is named `test.sh`. normally in terminal, we can run it with `./test.sh` (and I'm currently doing this with termux in anroid). Since I am using ionic, I don't have access to terminal nor a file executor. So my question is, how will I be able to execute a shell script using ionic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps integrate xterm.js onto your ionic project, which is a js terminal.

Comment: That project is way too old for me to remember or test it. But I assume what you proposed is correct and mark it as accepted answer